# How can i Pass values gotten from an observable function as the parameter to another observable function

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

the variables have all been declared judiciously, how can i pass the value gotten from the first observable function which is this.acNum as the parameter to resolve the second observable function as shown in ngOnInit, when i do this, it seems the value of this.acNum is actually empty but it shows up in my component html template.

```
ngOnInit() {   
    this.getFQ(8030495); 
    this.getHS(this.acNum);  
}

getFormQ(formqid){
    this.getFQService.GetFQ(fqid).subscribe({
        next: fQDetails => {
            this.fQDetails = fQDetails;
            //populating app details
            this.acNum = this.fQDetails["data"]["data1"];
            this.appName = this.fQDetails["data"]["data1"];
        },
        error: err=> {
            this.errorMessage = err;
        }
    })
};

getHSC(hsc){
    this.gethscservice.GetHsC(hsc).subscribe({
        next:HScResp=>{ this.HScResp = HScResp;
            console.log(HScResp["data"]);
        },
    });
};
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: this is **asynchronous** please refer first to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call before moving on. After you get the hang of that, please look into chaining requests with rxjs `switchMap` or `mergeMap`.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
this.getFQService.GetFQ(fqid).subscribe(res1:any => {
    this.acNum = res1["data"]["data1"];
    this.appName = res1["data"]["data1"];
    this.gethscservice.GetHsC(this.acNum).subscribe(res2 => {
  });
});
```

or you can use **mergeMap**

```
var result = this.getFQService.GetFQ(fqid).pipe(
  mergeMap(res1 => this.gethscservice.GetHsC(res1["data"]["data1"]))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call your `getHSC` function in your `getFormQ` function when you have set the value for `this.acNum` or have a look at the comment of @AJT82.

Answer (score 0):

Try forkJoin with mergeMap:

```
ngOnInit() {   
 this.getFQ(8030495); 
 var first = this.acNum();
 var second = this.getHS();

 const result = first.pipe(mergeMap(q => forkJoin(second(q)));
 }
```